# Declaring arrays in ZSH

Tags: shell, command-line, zsh

I'm having trouble converting a shell script to zsh. I have the following array defined, but it is throwing the error `unknown file attribute: \n`. (I'm converting a dotfiles repo to my zsh)

```
declare -r -a FILES_TO_SOURCE=(
    "bash_aliases"
    "bash_exports"
    "bash_functions"
    "bash_options"
    "bash_prompt"
    "bash.local"
)
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From `man zshbuiltins`, under the entry for `typeset` (of which `declare` is a synonym):

> For each *name=value* assignment, the parameter *name* is set to *value*.  Note that arrays  currently  cannot
>                 be  assigned  in  **typeset** expressions, only scalars and integers.

Try this instead:

```
declare -a FILES_TO_SOURCE
FILES_TO_SOURCE=(
    "bash_aliases"
    "bash_exports"
    "bash_functions"
    "bash_options"
    "bash_prompt"
    "bash.local"
)
declare -r FILES_TO_SOURCE
```

That being said that list of files is going to have to change here too most likely for compatibility (assuming you've used bash-isms in those files which seems likely).